# Django or Drupal for 10gb entries

Tags: django, drupal

What would be better option, drupal or django if there was data of 10gb of entries to be imported from MSSQL darabase

One of requirements is to have editors access so they can update content at anytime.

Comment: What kind of data ? What kind of prezentation ?

Comment: title, description and images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is an **application framework**, Drupal is ready to go **CMS system**. It's a mostly database question which in both cases is MySQL or Postgre. So the question is: **WHAT exactly are you doing?** :)

Anyway I'd choose Django and build my own platform on it anyway :P but if you are looking for ready to go CMS solution and you have no clue about programming in Python and you don't want to learn it then choose.. (I will not say it at laud!) - easy as that.

Comment: One point your missing is the amount of features available in Drupal without actually being able to code, vs the Django way where a developer is essential. Also Drupal hosting is a lot easier since it's PHP. But as you said, it really depends on what OP wants to do (along with experience) that determines which tool is best to use.